# Working cmd command not executing correctly when called via cmd.exe /C

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am trying to execute a one line command including a `for` loop by calling it via `cmd /C`.

The command itself executes a `for`loop to check if a service is running (in this case JBoss) and exits with an error code if it is stopped:

```
 for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %H in ('sc query JBossEAP7 ^| findstr "STATE"') do if "%H"=="STOPPED" exit /B 1
```

This works fine if I enter it in a `cmd` window or use it in a `.bat` file (if I substitute `%` for `%%`).

However, if I try to call it using `cmd /C` (like this

```
cmd /C for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %H in ('sc query JBossEAP7 ^| findstr "STATE"') do if "%H"=="STOPPED" exit /B 1
```

I get the error `| was unexpected at this time`.

Can anyone point me towards a way how I can call this via `cmd` without using a batch file?

Comment: Its likely got something to do with your usage of quotes. You need to find a different way of seperating your nested parameters such that you can call: `cmd /C "YourCommandHere"`. I don't have mutch batch experience by try combining backticks into your params: `\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cmd /c " commands "` in your command:

```
cmd /C "for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %H in ('sc query JBossEAP7 ^| findstr "STATE"') do if "%H"=="STOPPED" exit /B 1"
```

Or, in your `for` loop command `"sc query JBossEAP7 | findstr "STATE""`:

```
cmd /C for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %H in ('"sc query JBossEAP7 | findstr "STATE""') do if "%H"=="STOPPED" exit /B 1
```

---

- You can also use another option to do the same using operator `&&`:

```
cmd /c sc query JBossEAP7 | findstr STATE.*STOPPED && exit /b 1

cmd /c "sc query JBossEAP7 | findstr STATE.*STOPPED && exit /b 1"

cmd/csc query JBossEAP7|findstr STATE.*STOPPED&&exit /b 1"

cmd/c|(sc query JBossEAP7 | find "STOPPED" && exit/b 1)

cmd/c| sc query JBossEAP7 | find "STOPPED" && exit/b 1

cmd/c"sc query JBossEAP7|find "STOPPED"&&exit/b 1"

cmd/c|sc query JBossEAP7|find "STOPPED"&&exit/b 1
```

---

**Obs.:** The command `findstr STATE.*STOPPED` will find in the same line where you have:

```
rem :: STATE + One_or_More_Characters + STOPPED
```

```
> sc query vds
SERVICE_NAME: vds
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

> sc query vds | findstr STATE.*STOPPED
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED

             |----------------------| 
 
        STATE +        .*       + STOPPED
```

---

```
rem :: Omitting output >nul and using end End Of Line in findstr /e STOPPED
```

```
> sc query vds | findstr /e STOPPED>nul 
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
```

---

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[Find /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

**[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

**[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**

Comment: Wow, this is a really comprehensive answer!

Comment: @buddemat You can omit output if you need `>nul` : **`cmd/c|sc query JBossEAP7|find "STOPPED">nul&&exit/b 1`**